# wrong scope from $compile in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, compilation, directive

i have a problem with $compile and get the correct scope to get my data.

i made a simplified codepen here

http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/GgZvXO?editors=001

but this is the problem, i try to put some data from one directive to his child-directive

```
...
angular.element(wrapper).append($compile("<navigationlist data-title="+navi.title+" navigation-list-data='data'></navigationlist>")(scope));
....

app.directive('navigationlist', function($compile) {
    var link = function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.navigationListData);
    }
    return {
    scope:{
      navigationListData: "="
    },
    replace: true;
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<ul class="navigation-sub-list"><li ng-repeat="item in navigationListData">{{item.title}}</li></ul>',
    link: link
    };  
});
```

the log of the console shows me the correct values but the view renders just the last object of my navigation array, which you can see in the codepen...

anybody has some ideas how i solve that problem??

**UPDATE**

if i have not choosen the best way to build my navigation, perhaps somebody can show me how i can build it better ;)

i need this html structure

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="main">
        <ul>
            <li>mainitem1</li>
            <li>mainitem2</li>
            <li>mainitem3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="subs">
        <div class="sub_lvl1">
            <ul class="sub_mainitem1">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item1</li>
            </ul> 
            <ul class="sub_mainitem2">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub_mainitem3">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
            </ul>  
        </div>
        <div class="sub_lvl2">
            <ul class="sub_sub_mainitem1">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

from this

```
var navigation = [
    {"title": "Album", "child": {"title": "category", data: ["item1", "item2", "item3"], "child": {"title": "gallery", data: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]}}},
    {"title": "Pages", "child": {"title": "pages", data: ["item1", "item2", "item3"]}},
    {"title": "Statistik"}
]
```

the numbers of childs can change so i cant use a "static" template

best regards
gregor ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you use compile like you have, it only knows about data in context of the scope that you pass in. In your case, you are expecting it to somehow use your local `data` variable that you have defined within your loop. to use the rendering setup you currently have, you would need to reference the full path to that data in your template (i.e. `navi[i][key].data`) which would kinda suck. Especially since that would need to change as you got deeper into the tree structure.

To be honest, the way you have your directives setup makes very little sense to me. Why don't you just loop through the children again in the navigationsub template, instead of doing crazy logic in the controller and appending compiled elements?

Comment: thank you for your comment.
but i dont know how i should write my directive to get the html structure, which i have updated in my post above. perhaps you can  show me, how can i achieve that ;)

Comment: Your navigation data structure is also not ideal, now that i look at the simplified example. You have sub navigation items all grouped together. This is not a common way to do navigation, but without seeing how you want it to display, it's hard for me to say it's "wrong".

Comment: hi, yes my idea was if i group subnaviagtions together i can make one animation with "sub_lvl1" div when i hover over one mainitem and display the subbnavigation insinde "sub_lvl1", when i hover another mainitem i dont need anymore an animation for "sub_lvl1" because it is still open so i onlyneed to animate the content (e.g. fadeout sub_mainitem1 and fadein sub_mainitem2).

Answer (score 0):

ok i have done another approach to setup my navigation. i rebuild the navigationarray that it represents more the html markup which i need and splitted it in 2 items and subNavi has for every depth his own array

```
$scope.mainNavi = [];
$scope.subNavi = {depth1: Array[2], depth2: Array[1],...};
```

but thank you for your answers ;)

http://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/pvyWzM?editors=101

now everythink works as expected ;)